# LESS when statement (or) multiple conditions

Tags: less

How can I create a LESS when statement with multiple conditions?

This is what I have at the moment, with only one condition, but
I would like to check if `myVariable` is "`value1`" **OR** "`value2`"

```
& when (@myVariable = 'value1') {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: See [the documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature-guard-logical-operators).

Answer (score 6):

In LESS the AND operator is identified by the word `and` however the OR operator is identified by `,`.

Here is an example of how you would use the OR (`,`) operator:

```
& when (@myVariable = 'value1'), (@myVariable = 'value2') {
    background: red;
}
```

In the LESS official discussion forum there is [a recent thread](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2705) that is asking the use of the `OR` word to identify OR operator instead of (or maybe in addition to) using `,`.

Currently it's in the *ReadyForImplementation* state which means that if a volunteer starts to develop this feature it will become part of the LESS core in the (near) future.

---

**UPDATE 2016 February:**

In [2.6 version](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#260), released at the end of january, are added the following features:

- Added "or" keyword and allowed arbitrary logical expression in guards
- Logical operator `and` now has higher precence then logical operator `or`

So, since this version you'll be able to use also `OR` operator instead of `,`

Comment: it is a case sensitive `or` not as you mentioned an `OR`